# Fluent Validation - Validator for "Pure" collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

My API supports bulk creation of an entity.
How does `FluentValidation` supports validation for a pure collection?

This is the controller's create bulk signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task<IActionResult> CreateBulk([FromBody] IEnumerable<MyClass> model))
```

I would like to validate that the collection sent is not null or empty by implementing `FluentValidation` based validator.

Comment: Not sure if its possible. I think that you'd need to create a dto/view model, make the collection a property of the dto, create a validator for the dto with a validation rule on the property, then update this method to accept the dto. I'd normally do my end points that way anyway.

Comment: @rgvlee Thank you for your comment, but I need definite answer. I reached the same endpoint regard this question

Answer (score 0):

Initially I didn't think this was possible but it turns out it can be done. At the end of the day a collection is a container so you should be able to create a validator for it like you can for any other container with a child list.

The solution is to define a validator for the collection itself:

```
public class ListOfMyClassValidator : AbstractValidator<List<MyClass>>
{
    public ListOfMyClassValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x).Must(x => x.Any()).WithMessage("The list cannot be empty");

        RuleForEach(x => x).SetValidator(new MyClassValidator());
    }
}
```

I've specified `RuleForEach` here so that each list item is also validated (if you have a `MyClass` validator). You could skip this part by setting `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` to true when configuring FV however the former method is the recommended way.

I did try this with an `IEnumerable<MyClass>` however that didn't fire the validator. Same with an `IList<MyClass>`. I haven't investigated why as functionally the model binder is happy binding to a `List<T>`.

[Working solution](https://github.com/rgvlee/StackOverflow/tree/master/Question60650516)

[image]

Comment: How did you implement that class? The repo does not have the implementation either.

Comment: The working solution works for me when I request the POST end point with an empty sequence. I'll add a screenshot to my answer.